# Destruction order when jthread is a class member

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, c++20, destructor

I have a class which handles synchronization of some threads.

```
class ThreadHandler {
    std::vector<std::jthread> threads;
    std::mutex mut;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    int some_int;
    // some other synchronization related variables
};
```

In C++, member destructors are called in reverse order, so the destructor for `cv` is called before the destructor for `threads`. Because the destructor for `threads` joins the `jthread`s, there's a period of of time when `cv` and `mut` have been destructed and the `jthread`s are still running. Is that a problem?

Comment: Depends on the rest of your code. Are any of the threads running something that requires `cv` or `mut` (or `some_int`) to exist? *(Consider this: If you define but never use `cv` then the timing of its destruction cannot affect anything, and this is consistent with the posted code.)*

Comment: Yes, you can assume the jthreads are using ```mut```, ```cv```, ```some_int```, and other synchronization related variables.

Comment: Could the threads use cv and mut after they're destroyed?

Comment: @user253751 in the code, yes. The threads run until ```std::stop_token::stop_requested``` returns true, which doesn't happen until ```join``` is called, I think.

Comment: So you know that your program could use an object after it's destroyed and you're asking whether it's a problem to use an object after it's destroyed?

Comment: I believe the answer to the OP is an "obviously, yes that is a problem. reorder your members." but I need a sanity check because I've never seen this issue mentioned before.

Comment: Yes, the answer is it's a problem, and I've seen the error in various forms in real code many times. In those cases, one has some data used by an async operation after some handle to the async operation. It is even more nefarious if the handle is in a base class (e.g. a base "Thread" class).

Comment: Why don't you move the vector to the end? Otherwise, you'll need a detructor that `clear`s the vector.

Comment: @Bobby *"I've never seen this issue mentioned before"* -- If you pull in some other tidbits, this would be covered by cppreference.com in [Acess outside of lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Access_outside_of_lifetime), since you say the thread could access `cv` after the destructor of `cv` is called (ending the lifetime of `cv`) and **before** the storage for `cv` is released/reused (which would be after all member destructors finish). *Interestingly, this article does not cover access **after** the storage is released or reused.*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments:

> Could the threads use cv and mut after they're destroyed? – user253751
> @user253751 in the code, yes. The threads run until std::stop_token::stop_requested returns true, which doesn't happen until join is called, I think. – Bobby

the asker knows the code could use these objects after they're destroyed.

So the question is: Is it okay to use an object after it's been destroyed?

And the answer is: No.

The computer doesn't care about which order you write your member variables, but it does care about using objects after they're destroyed. If the threads had no chance to use `cv` and `mut` after they were destroyed, then it would be okay. If they could use `cv` and `mut` after they're destroyed, then it's not okay and you have to fix that or your program will sometimes crash.