# Controlling class member layout AND destructor order

Tags: c++, class, constructor, destructor, micro-optimization

I have a class with two members.

```
class C {
    typeA a;
    typeB b;
};
```

Assume that there is no inheritance. There are three things I'm concerned about with this class.

1. the order in which the constructors for `a` and `b` are called
2. the order in which the destructors for `a` and `b` are called
3. the layout of `a` and `b` in memory

One reason I may care about (1) and (2) is [thread synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77588785/destruction-order-when-jthread-is-a-class-member). Some reasons I may care about (3) are:

4. padding
5. spatial locality with more than two class members
6. the first class member has memory offset 0

I want to be able to control (1)-(3) simultaneously. However, it seems that when I choose an order in memory, I also choose the order of the constructors and destructors. Is there a way to have control over (1)-(3) simultaneously?

Comment: Is the destruction order always the same as reverse construction order?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat In the solution I'm looking for, I'm fine with (1) dictating (2) by destruction order being reverse construction order, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Spell each individual member like this:

```
union {typeA a;};
```

This prevents them from being automatically constructed and destructed, allowing you to do it manually (`::new((void *)&a) typeA();` to construct, `a.~typeA();` to destruct).

Obligatory reminder that if you have exceptions enabled and `C`'s constructor is not `noexcept`, and one of the constructors throws, you need to destroy the members that were already constructed.

---

Took this as a challenge, wrote a tuple class with this feature:

```
OrderedTuple<
    //                          construction order
    //               key        |  type
    //               |          |  |
    OrderedTupleElem<"a"_const, 1, int>,
    OrderedTupleElem<"b"_const, 2, std::string>,
    OrderedTupleElem<"c"_const, 0, float>
> foo;

foo = {42, "bar", 1.23f};

std::cout << foo.get<"b"_const>() << '\n'; // "bar"
```

Implementation is below.

While it seems to work well so far, even in presence of exceptions, if you're going to use it in production, it's your job to cover it with tests to make sure I didn't mess up the RAII.

This requires C++23, but backporting to C++20 shouldn't be hard. (Or to C++17 if you get rid of the string keys.)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <auto>
struct ValueTag {};

template <
    auto K, // Arbitrary key.
    std::size_t I, // Construction order index.
    typename T // Element type.
>
struct OrderedTupleElem
{
    static constexpr std::size_t index = I;
    using type = T;

    union {T value;};

    constexpr OrderedTupleElem() {}
    constexpr ~OrderedTupleElem() {}

    constexpr T &DetailGetElem(ValueTag<K>) {return value;}
};

namespace detail
{
    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool IsOrderedTupleElemVar = false;
    template <auto K, std::size_t I, typename T>
    constexpr bool IsOrderedTupleElemVar<OrderedTupleElem<K, I, T>> = true;
    template <typename T>
    concept IsOrderedTupleElem = IsOrderedTupleElemVar<T>;

    template <typename T, typename...>
    struct FirstType {using type = T;};
}

template <detail::IsOrderedTupleElem ...P>
class OrderedTuple : P...
{
    using P::DetailGetElem...;

    static consteval auto MakeFuncArray(auto &&generate)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(P) > 0);
        std::array<decltype(+generate.template operator()<typename detail::FirstType<P...>::type, 0>()), sizeof...(P)> ret{};
        [&]<std::size_t ...I>(std::index_sequence<I...>)
        {
            ([&]{
                if (ret[P::index])
                    throw "Duplicate element index in `OrderedTuple<...>` template arguments.";
                ret[P::index] = +generate.template operator()<P, I>();
            }(), ...);
        }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(P)>{});
        return ret;
    }

    constexpr void DestroyFromIndex(std::size_t i)
    {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(P) > 0)
        {
            static constexpr auto arr = MakeFuncArray([]<typename T, std::size_t>
            {
                return [](OrderedTuple &self) noexcept
                {
                    using MemberType = T::type;
                    static_cast<T &>(self).value.~MemberType();
                };
            });

            while (i > 0)
            {
                i--;
                arr[i](*this);
            }
        }
    }

    struct ConstructorGuard
    {
        OrderedTuple &self;
        std::size_t i = 0;

        constexpr ConstructorGuard(OrderedTuple &self) : self(self) {}

        ConstructorGuard(const ConstructorGuard &) = delete;
        ConstructorGuard &operator=(const ConstructorGuard &) = delete;

        constexpr ~ConstructorGuard()
        {
            self.DestroyFromIndex(i);
        }

        void Finish() {i = 0;}

        template <typename T, typename ...Q>
        constexpr void Construct(Q &&... params)
        {
            if constexpr (sizeof...(P) > 0)
            {
                ::new((void *)&static_cast<T &>(self).value) T::type(std::forward<Q>(params)...);
                i++; // On a separate line, to be extra sure it doesn't happen if `Construct()` throws.
            }
        }
    };

    static constexpr void InOrder(auto &&func)
    {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(P) > 0)
        {
            static constexpr auto arr = MakeFuncArray([]<typename T, std::size_t I>
            {
                return [](decltype((func)) func) {func.template operator()<T, I>();};
            });
            for (auto x : arr)
                x(func);
        }
    }

  public:
    constexpr OrderedTuple()
    noexcept((std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<typename P::type> && ...))
    requires(std::is_default_constructible_v<typename P::type> && ...)
    {
        ConstructorGuard guard(*this);
        InOrder([&]<typename T, std::size_t>{guard.template Construct<T>();});
        guard.Finish();
    }

    constexpr OrderedTuple(const OrderedTuple &other)
    noexcept((std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<typename P::type> && ...))
    requires(std::is_copy_constructible_v<typename P::type> && ...)
    {
        ConstructorGuard guard(*this);
        InOrder([&]<typename T, std::size_t>{guard.template Construct<T>(static_cast<const T &>(other).value);});
        guard.Finish();
    }

    constexpr OrderedTuple(OrderedTuple &&other)
    noexcept((std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<typename P::type> && ...))
    requires(std::is_move_constructible_v<typename P::type> && ...)
    {
        ConstructorGuard guard(*this);
        InOrder([&]<typename T, std::size_t>{guard.template Construct<T>(std::move(static_cast<T &>(other).value));});
        guard.Finish();
    }

    constexpr OrderedTuple &operator=(const OrderedTuple &other)
    noexcept((std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable_v<typename P::type> && ...))
    requires(std::is_copy_assignable_v<typename P::type> && ...)
    {
        InOrder([&]<typename T, std::size_t>
        {
            static_cast<T &>(*this).value = static_cast<const T &>(other).value;
        });
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr OrderedTuple &operator=(OrderedTuple &&other)
    noexcept((std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<typename P::type> && ...))
    requires(std::is_move_assignable_v<typename P::type> && ...)
    {
        InOrder([&]<typename T, std::size_t>
        {
            static_cast<T &>(*this).value = std::move(static_cast<T &>(other).value);
        });
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr ~OrderedTuple() noexcept
    {
        DestroyFromIndex(sizeof...(P));
    }

    template <typename ...Q>
    constexpr OrderedTuple(Q &&... params)
    noexcept((std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<typename P::type, Q &&> && ...))
    requires(std::is_constructible_v<typename P::type, Q &&> && ...)
    {
        ConstructorGuard guard(*this);
        InOrder([&]<typename T, std::size_t I>
        {
            guard.template Construct<T>(std::get<I>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Q>(params)...)));
        });
        guard.Finish();
    }

    template <auto K>
    static constexpr bool contains_key = []{
        if constexpr (sizeof...(P) == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return requires(OrderedTuple &self){self.DetailGetElem(ValueTag<K>{});};
    }();

    template <auto K> requires contains_key<K> [[nodiscard]]       auto & get()       &  {return           this->DetailGetElem(ValueTag<K>{}) ;}
    template <auto K> requires contains_key<K> [[nodiscard]] const auto & get() const &  {return           this->DetailGetElem(ValueTag<K>{}) ;}
    template <auto K> requires contains_key<K> [[nodiscard]]       auto &&get()       && {return std::move(this->DetailGetElem(ValueTag<K>{}));}
    template <auto K> requires contains_key<K> [[nodiscard]] const auto &&get() const && {return std::move(this->DetailGetElem(ValueTag<K>{}));}
};

// ---

#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t N>
struct ConstString
{
    char array[N]{};
    consteval ConstString(const char (&source)[N])
    {
        std::copy_n(source, N, array);
    }
};

template <ConstString S>
[[nodiscard]] consteval decltype(S) operator""_const()
{
    return S;
}

#define MAKE_TEST_CLASS(A, copy_throws_) \
    struct A \
    { \
        A() {std::cout << #A "()\n";} \
        A(const A &) {std::cout << #A "(const " #A " &)\n"; if (copy_throws_) throw 42;} \
        A(A &&) {std::cout << #A "(" #A " &&)\n"; if (copy_throws_) throw 42;} \
        A &operator=(const A &) {std::cout << #A " &operator=(const " #A " &)\n"; return *this;} \
        A &operator=(A &&) {std::cout << #A " &operator=(" #A " &&)\n"; return *this;} \
        ~A() {std::cout << "~" #A "()\n";} \
    };

MAKE_TEST_CLASS(A, false)
MAKE_TEST_CLASS(B, false)
MAKE_TEST_CLASS(C, false)
MAKE_TEST_CLASS(X, true)

int main()
{
    {
        OrderedTuple<
            OrderedTupleElem<"foo"_const, 1, A>,
            OrderedTupleElem<"bar"_const, 2, B>,
            OrderedTupleElem<"baz"_const, 0, C>
        > x, y(x), z(std::move(x)), w(A(), B(), C{});
        x = y;
        x = std::move(y);

        (void)x.get<"foo"_const>();
        (void)x.get<"bar"_const>();
        (void)x.get<"baz"_const>();

        OrderedTuple<> empty1, empty2(empty1), empty3(std::move(empty1));
        empty1 = empty2;
        empty1 = std::move(empty2);
    }

    // Check partial destruction:
    try
    {
        OrderedTuple<
            OrderedTupleElem<"a"_const, 2, A>,
            OrderedTupleElem<"b"_const, 1, X>,
            OrderedTupleElem<"c"_const, 0, C>
        > foo(A(), X(), C{});
    }
    catch (...) {}
}
```

Comment: thanks, although I hope there is an answer that is still adheres to RAII

Comment: @Bobby There's nothing in the standard library. You can generalize this into your own wrapper if you want.

Comment: Can be done without "_const" in C++20. But needs concept to constrain the name argument. I'd rather make `ConstString` a monoid with a `static constexpr array<char,N> value` value and a lambda initializer, with Alphabet filtering.

Comment: @Red.Wave *"Can be done without "_const""* I know, but I wanted a generalized index type to allow integers if one wants them. *"make ConstString a monoid"* What is a monoid? Can you show a small code sample?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat actually the way you did is monostate too.  I misspelled it first. All instances of a monostate class are equivalent. So there's no need for none-static data members. In constexpr context, it should not make much difference. But I want to keep the class trivial. I don't know which implementation ICEs sooner: needs stress testing the cimpiler.

Answer (score 2):

Most classes in C++ have optionality, so although one can prevent constructors being called with enough effort and care, it is often enough to prevent meaningful initialization.

Take your example of synchronization. Suppose you have a strong reason to desire the ordering:

```
class ThreadHandler {
    std::jthread m_thread;
    ThreadData m_data; // used concurrently
};
```

Then you can ensure ordering:

```
ThreadHandler() : m_data(...) {
    m_thread = std::jthread([&] { /* thread logic */ });
}

~ThreadHandler() {
    m_thread = {};
}
```

With that said, it is rare to want or need simultaneous control of (1)-(3). The `ThreadHandler` class is fairly typical. We want the handle to the operation to be constructed after the data it uses and to be destructed before the data it uses. But the handle to the operation is barely used otherwise. It is an RAII object. Its layout in memory is unimportant. It might matter how the internals of ThreadData are layed out, but we have free control over this.

Comment: I'm not understanding this answer. You mention "optionality." I assume this in reference to ```std::optional```, but you don't use it. You seem to imply that your constructor for ```ThreadHandler``` forces reverse construction order, but I don't think it does. ```m_thread``` is just default constructed before entering the body of the constructor. I'm not sure how the destructor works, but I didn't want to think about it until I understood everything else.

Comment: I'm not even sure ```m_thread = /* something */;``` will compile. Give me a minute to test.

Comment: By "optionality", I mean that most types have an "empty" state. That is typically the default constructed and often also the moved-from state. Because of that, you can default construct the out-of-order member and then move-assign to it within the constructor.

Comment: `m_thread = /* something */` is move-assignment, where something is an initialization of a temporary jthread. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread/operator%3D

Comment: Re-worded for clarity.